# Running quser.exe in PowerShell scripts works in IDE but not when running as a service

Tags: powershell, cmd, windows-services, windows-console

If I run the following snippet in a console window or in ISE it works as expected, listing the active user sessions on the local computer:

`(Invoke-Expression "$env:windir\system32\quser.exe") -replace '\s{2,}', ',' | ConvertFrom-Csv`

Unfortunately this is not a console application, rather a PowerShell script that is installed as a service. The service runs as LocalSystem (not LocalService). When the service attempts to run this code it outputs the following error:

`The term 'C:\Windows\system32\quser.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.`

I contacted Sapien support and was informed that *A service runs with no profile and does not have execution access to the system folders. You need to give the service account execution access to the exe and its support DLLs as well as using the full path to the EXE.*

I have proven (I think) that the security principal has access to quser. I used PSExen to open a PowerShell console running as LocalSystem and successfully ran the quser application:

[image: Running quser as NTAUTHORITY\LocalSystem]

The issue MUST be that I'm running as a service. Does anyone know how I can access/use QUser in a service?

I guess the real question would be, how can services running as LocalSystem execute applications in system folders?

Comment: Where does the cmdlet "New-ServiceEvent" come from? I suspect it's not running the quser command or can't find the path to it under the service credentials. I'd add a transcript (Start-Transcript/Stop Transcript) to the function so that you can see where it errors out.

Comment: `New-ServiceEvent` is a logging function elsewhere in the script, it works perfectly and logs the error `Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Message' because it is an empty string.`. The issue is `$QUserToStringOutput` is empty. meaning this isn't working: `$QUserToStringOutput = cmd.exe /C $Env:SystemRoot\System32\quser.exe 2>$null`

Comment: If you add a transcript, it'll tell you whats happening when the "$QUserToStringOutput =" line is attempted, as if you run it in the console. Have you also tried "$QUserToStringOutput = & quser.exe"?

Comment: Sorry I should have said, that was a great suggestion :) I'm doing it just now

Comment: I tried `& quser.exe`, it said it could not be found. I then tried `$QUserToStringOutput = & $ENV:SystemRoot\System32\quser.exe 2>$null` which returned `The term 'C:\Windows\System32\quser.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.`. I'm a little lost as to why this isn't working in the service but does work in ISE/console?

Comment: FYI, if I run `& quser 2>$null` or `& $ENV:SystemRoot\System32\quser.exe 2>$null` in the console, it works. This is all due to running it as a service or as the SYSTEM account.

Comment: Can you change the user and run it as yourself? (i.e. is it running as the SYSTEM account that is the issue or running as a service)

Comment: It's because its running as a service, when running the service as my MicrosoftAccount (local admin) the same error occurs `The term 'C:\Windows\System32\quser.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.`

Comment: Specifically _how_ are you running a PowerShell script as a service?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I'm using an option in Sapien's PowerShell Studio 2019 (https://www.sapien.com/blog/2017/07/12/write-a-windows-service-in-powershell/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that whatever tool you are using to run your PowerShell script as a service is 32-bit, and there is not a `quser.exe` in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`.

If this is the case, you can probably work around this on a 64-bit OS by running `C:\Windows\Sysnative\quser.exe` (see [File System Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector) in the documentation for details).

If that's the case, I would say that the information you got ("service runs with no profile and does not have execution access to the system folders") is simply incorrect.

Comment: I feel incredibly embarrassed... I didn't know this was a thing (I've only ever recognised 32/64 seperation in the registry). My service is 32-bit (by design) and the system I'm testing/developing on is 64-bit; and so you're likely on the right lines. Interestingly, I can find quser in System32 but not in SysWOW64. `Sysnative` doesn't exist for me. I'm reading the link you provided now

Comment: The `Sysnative` name is "virtual" in WoW (the 32-bit emulator in 64-bit Windows). Try opening a 32-bit copy of `cmd.exe` and enter the command: `dir C:\Windows\Sysnative\quser.exe` and you'll see that it works (WoW redirects the`Sysnative` name internally to the 64-bit `System32` directory).

Comment: FYI you're definitely correct, as I didn't know there was this difference between 32b and 64b I never thought to run the command in a 32b console. Seems to make so much sense now, and I can finally replicate the error in the console

Comment: you nailed it, thank you so much. I'll give the docs a good read. I'm shocked this hasn't been an issue for me before! Will award bounty in 18h